# Speeding up calculation of transaction latency

Tags: r

I'm developing a clustering model using an expanded take on RFM. One of the features I am adding is "periodicity" - the average time between transactions. I have a solution (below) but it is very slow and clunky.

The code gets a unique list of customer numbers,
loops of the list subsetting the dataframe for each customer.
Sorts unique dates in descending order and passes to the days_calc function.
This function takes the dates, duplicates the column, removes the first entry in the duplicated column, adds a null in the last position. Then subtracts column b from column a.

This produces the expected result but is very slow, taking around 3 hours for 30k customers. The final set of customers will be approx 300k so I would like to make this more practical.

Sample:

```
   CUST_CODE      SHOP_DATE           
   <fct>          <dttm>             
 1 CUST0000000031 2006-04-16 00:00:00
 2 CUST0000000068 2006-04-14 00:00:00
 3 CUST0000000068 2006-04-10 00:00:00
 4 CUST0000000131 2006-04-16 00:00:00
 5 CUST0000000164 2006-04-11 00:00:00
 6 CUST0000000180 2006-04-15 00:00:00
 7 CUST0000000180 2006-04-10 00:00:00
 8 CUST0000000324 2006-04-15 00:00:00
 9 CUST0000000324 2006-04-11 00:00:00
10 CUST0000000358 2006-04-14 00:00:00
```

Expected Output:

```
$days.between
Time difference of NA secs

$days.between
Time differences in days
[1]  4 NA

$days.between
Time difference of NA secs

$days.between
Time difference of NA secs

$days.between
Time differences in days
[1]  5 NA

$days.between
Time differences in days
[1]  4 NA

$days.between
Time difference of NA secs
```

Where the output is the difference between the dates for each customer, if customers have only 1 transaction, it has NA.
Ideally, I would like a list of vectors of integers rather than difftime objects but I can't figure out how to structure the data this way.

```
# Function to calculate the cadence between each transaction date and the previous date for each customer
# takes an object with CUST_CODE and SHOP_DATE.
# Copies the list of dates removing the first entry and adding NULL as the last entry.
# This allows subtraction of columns.
# returns a vector of the days between the columns
days_calc = function(dates) {
    dates.list1 = dates[,"SHOP_DATE"]
    dates.list2 = dates.list1[-1,]
    dates.list2[nrow(dates.list2)+1,] = NULL

    df = data.frame(c(dates.list1, dates.list2))
    days.between = df %>%
        mutate(days.between = SHOP_DATE - SHOP_DATE.1) %>%
        select(days.between)
    return(as.vector(days.between))
}

# Prepares the data to go into days_calc function
# Slice the table into customer numbers and transaction dates
# Dates must be ordered in descending order to allow the days_calc function to work correctly.
dates = tbl[, c("CUST_CODE", "SHOP_DATE")] %>%
    group_by(CUST_CODE) %>%
    distinct(SHOP_DATE) %>%
    arrange(desc(SHOP_DATE))  %>%
    select(c(CUST_CODE,SHOP_DATE) )

# Generate a list of unique customer numbers to subset the customer table
customers = tbl[,"CUST_CODE"] %>%
    unique() %>%
    as.vector()

# Loop over the list of customers.
# Subset the overall table by each customer number
# Add the returned vector to a list of days_between vectors
days = c()
for( i in 1:length(customers)) {
    days = c(days, days_calc(dates %>% filter(CUST_CODE == customers[i])))
    if(i %% 50 == 0){
        print(paste(c(round((i / length(customers)*100), 2), "%"), collapse = ""))
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll get help much more quickly if you include a *small*, illustrative set of sample data in the question itself. Say, 5-20 rows and only the relevant columns. You can then also show the expected output for the sample input so people have something to test against. It will help people understand the problem and lower the threshold of work needed to try a solution. (Note that `dput()` is really nice for making a copy/pasteable dataset. E.g., `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:20, ]))` for the first 20 rows)

Comment: Thanks Gregor, I've edited the question, hopefully this is a better format.

Comment: Much clearer. Clarifying questions: your output looks pretty useless to me. Would you rather have it in a data frame? And do you really need the customers with one transaction included, or could they just be omitted? And you are using a date-time class, but all the times are `00:00:00`. Does your actual data have times that matter, or could we simplify to just using the date, not the datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward  `dplyr` solution. Oddly enough, adding an `NA` to the front of the datediff vector coerces to numeric, solving that problem simply.

```
result = df %>% 
  group_by(CUST_CODE) %>% 
  arrange(SHOP_DATE) %>%
  mutate(days_from_previous_shop = c(NA, diff(SHOP_DATE))) 

## full data frame result
result
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
# # Groups:   CUST_CODE [7]
#    CUST_CODE      SHOP_DATE           days_from_previous_shop
#    <fct>          <dttm>                                <dbl>
#  1 CUST0000000068 2006-04-10 00:00:00                      NA
#  2 CUST0000000180 2006-04-10 00:00:00                      NA
#  3 CUST0000000164 2006-04-11 00:00:00                      NA
#  4 CUST0000000324 2006-04-11 00:00:00                      NA
#  5 CUST0000000068 2006-04-14 00:00:00                       4
#  6 CUST0000000358 2006-04-14 00:00:00                      NA
#  7 CUST0000000180 2006-04-15 00:00:00                       5
#  8 CUST0000000324 2006-04-15 00:00:00                       4
#  9 CUST0000000031 2006-04-16 00:00:00                      NA
# 10 CUST0000000131 2006-04-16 00:00:00                      NA

## this seems nicer to me
filter(result, !is.na(days_from_previous_shop))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   CUST_CODE [3]
#   CUST_CODE      SHOP_DATE           days_from_previous_shop
#   <fct>          <dttm>                                <dbl>
# 1 CUST0000000068 2006-04-14 00:00:00                       4
# 2 CUST0000000180 2006-04-15 00:00:00                       5
# 3 CUST0000000324 2006-04-15 00:00:00                       4
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = "CUST_CODE      SHOP_DATE           
 1 CUST0000000031 '2006-04-16 00:00:00'
 2 CUST0000000068 '2006-04-14 00:00:00'
 3 CUST0000000068 '2006-04-10 00:00:00'
 4 CUST0000000131 '2006-04-16 00:00:00'
 5 CUST0000000164 '2006-04-11 00:00:00'
 6 CUST0000000180 '2006-04-15 00:00:00'
 7 CUST0000000180 '2006-04-10 00:00:00'
 8 CUST0000000324 '2006-04-15 00:00:00'
 9 CUST0000000324 '2006-04-11 00:00:00'
10 CUST0000000358 '2006-04-14 00:00:00'", header = T)

df$SHOP_DATE = as.POSIXct(df$SHOP_DATE)
```

Comment: Genius! That's perfect and removes the need for more processing later. Thanks a lot Gregor!